# Destroyed users break draft pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, deleted-users, draft

I just destroyed the user who made [this draft](https://stackoverflow.com/error/documentation/java/drafts/23026), and now the page 500's.

I could *maybe* understand deleting a user's pending drafts, but then the page should return a 404. The 500 error seems to indicate that there's something in the code unhappy about displaying a nuked user.

Comment: Probably trying to associate the draft to the user and nothing handles when the user doesn't exist.

Comment: Looks like it's a 404 now. For a _destroyed_ user (typically spam and other nonsense), this seems reasonable.